# Rigid body changes position while keyframing "animation" and "dynamics" checkboxes

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, animation-nodes

I try to animate interaction about two rigid body objects. One of them is animated, the second one is animated but just a frame before the interaction I switch its behavior by keyframing "animated" and "dynamics" checkboxes in Rigid Body properties.

In a simple example I made it works well but in the real project I am doing after disactivating the "animated"checkbox, the rigid body objects suprisingly moves back to another position

The only difference between projects is animation nodes add-onn used to multiply objects. May it be the reason?

Please find linked below blender files. Any answers would be highly appreciated.

https://we.tl/eTJqTAsTN0

Jakub

[image: example]
[image].

P.S No idea why, but after reloading the second file the bottle loses its rigid bodiness...

Comment: Wouldn't a [breakable rigid body constraint](https://imgur.com/a/pbK3QwE) be easier to maintain? That would remove all the fine tuned keying.

Comment: Hey, I used breakable rigid body constraint and it worked greatly! Thank you very much!